# Transport from Frankfurt Hahn Airport

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, frankfurt, hhn

What is the best and cheapest way of transport from HHN airport Germany to Leonardo City Hotel,Mailander Strassse 1 Frankfurt ?

Comment: Depends on whatever you mean with 'best', so I vote to close as opinion based. 'Best' and 'cheapest' are ususally condradicting requirements when it comes to travel options.

Comment: Go to the website of the local transport in the area or Bahn.de (the train site) and enter the addresses, adjust time and get the instructions. Often several options.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, maybe you need to define what you mean by "best" and "cheapest". 
Also a lot depends on what time of the day you are arriving. There exists [Flibco buses](https://www.flibco.com/en#/booking) which take you to Frankfurt (Main) Hbf. From there you can [take U Bahn/S Bahn](https://www.rmv.de/en/) to reach Frankfurt (Main) Süd and then walk your way to the hotel (approx. 20 minutes).

Costs (approximately) 16€ and then an additional 2,9€ for the public transport. Take a look at the schedules and plan accordingly.

If you have baggage, it might worth be an option to use the [Taxi](https://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?menu=by_taxi&cc=en).

Also, as many would have pointed out on the internet, Hahn is quite far away from Frankfurt (Main) City and you might want to rethink if flights into Frankfurt (Main) Airport are relatively afordable/convenient.

Also, I could find solutions on the German [Deutsche Bahn](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?ld=15037&protocol=https:&seqnr=4&ident=0w.0480037.1504436529&rt=1&OK#focus). The costs however are not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Frankfurt Hahn Airport is a former military airfield 125 km from Frankfurt, often used by discount airlines like RyanAir. It has bad connections to public transport.

- Taking a bus is probably the cheapest option.
- Taking a taxi cab is probably the best option.

Depends on how much you are prepared to pay, and what your comfort is worth.

Comment: Can you at least add details for one option of public transport (bus) travel? As it is your 'answer' should be no more than a comment in my view.

Comment: @Willeke, details depend on when the OP wants to travel. But this is closed now anyway.